Proving the identity $(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}-\frac{\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{r})}{r^3}$
Given that $\mathbf{r}=x\hat {\mathbf{i}}+y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+z\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ is the position vector, $r=|\mathbf{r}|$, $\hat{r}=\mathbf{r}/r$, and $\mathbf{a}$ is an arbitrary vector, show that $$(\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}-\frac{\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{r})}{r^3}$$
My attempt:
Suppose that $\mathbf{a}=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$, then $\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla=\left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial z}\right)\frac{(x,y,z)}{r}$ and \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbf{a}}{r}-\frac{\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{r})}{r^3}&=\frac{(f_1,f_2,f_3)}{r}-\frac{(x,y,z)(xf_1+yf_2+zf_3)}{r^3}\\&=\frac{\left((r^2-x^2)f_1,(r^2-y^2)f_2,(r^2-z^2)f_3\right)}{r^3}
\end{align*}
I am stuck on proving that $\frac{(r^2-x^2)f_1}{r^3}=\frac{x}{r}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}$. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

$\mathbf a\cdot\nabla$ is the $\mathbf a$-directional derivative, so it acts just like a partial derivative. By the product rule,
$$
  (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\hat{\mathbf r} = (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\frac{\mathbf r}{r} = \frac1{r}(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\mathbf r + \mathbf r(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\frac1{r}.
$$
The expression $(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\mathbf r$ is the directional derivative of the identity function $\mathbf r \mapsto \mathbf r$, thus
$$
  (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\mathbf r = \mathbf a.
$$
Now by the power rule,
$$
  (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\frac1{r} = \frac{-(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)r}{r^2}.
$$
To compute the numerator, note that $r = \sqrt{\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r}$;
by the chain, power, and product rules,
$$
  (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)r = \frac1{2r}(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)(\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r) = \frac1r(\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf r).
$$
Putting this altogether gives the desired result:
$$
    (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\hat{\mathbf r} = \frac{\mathbf a}r - \frac{\mathbf r(\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf r)}{r^3}.
$$

Could you help elaborate on $ (\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)r = \frac1{2r}(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)(\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r)$, thank you!

@BoweiTang Write $\mathbf a\cdot\nabla$ as $D$ for brevity. $r = \sqrt R$ where $R = \mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r$; by the chain rule $$Dr = \frac{\partial r}{\partial R}DR.$$ By the power rule $\partial r/\partial R = 1/2\sqrt R = 1/2r$, thus $$Dr = \frac1{2r}DR$$ as desired.

Thank you very much!!
